# how to pass array in whereMonth method of laravel eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, where-in

I have to pass an array for whereMonth..

```
$months = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12'];

$user_date = UserDetails::where('userId', '=', $id)
    ->whereMonth('created_at', $months[1])
    ->whereYear('created_at', date('Y'))
    ->pluck('date');
```

Comment: ? whereMontth means only 1 month what you want?

Comment: whereMonth('created_at', $months) I want this,so it can check for all months. Not only for $months[0] = '01'

Comment: if you want to check all months means use only `whereYear()` and if you want 2 months between then you need to user `whereBetween()`

Comment: @KamleshPaul But i want the records for specific month,i checked for whereYear(), it gives all records.

Answer (score 2):

You need to used the [whereRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#whereraw-orwhereraw) Method here

```
$months = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];

$user_date = UserDetails::selectRaw("*,MONTH(created_at) as month_at")
    ->where('userId', '=', $id)
    ->whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) in ('.implode(',',$months).')')
    ->whereYear('created_at', date('Y'))
    ->pluck('date');
```

Answer (score 0):

To Avoid Raw Expressions You can use **Virtual Columns**

1.Add this to your Migration after `created_at` column

```
$table->char('created_at_month',3)->virtualAs('DATE_FORMAT(created_at,"%m")');
```

Run your Migrations

Now You can Run the following query to get the records that is created at specific month

```
$months = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12'];

$user_date = UserDetails::where('userId', '=', $id)
    ->whereIn('created_at_month', $months)
    ->whereYear('created_at', date('Y'))
    ->pluck('date');
```

If you want to Know more check the Below links

1. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-modifiers
2. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp

Comment: This will over complicate the whole table just for a single filter that I believe shouldn't be suggested to user unless there is a valid requirement to introduce such change, the solution posted by @Jignesh Joisar is far better than this

Comment: I have Clearly Mentioned that if you want to avoid raw expressions and increase the performance he can use my solution @M Khalid Junaid